# How to refresh dropdown in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a basic dropdown setup like this:

(Obviously in the real world `fetchValues()` would go to a server):

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const fetchValues = () => Promise.resolve(["option1", "option2"]);

function Dropdown(props) {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
      props.fetchValues().then(setOptions);
  }, [props.fetchValues]);

  return <select>{options && options.map(o => <option>{o}</option>)}</select>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dropdown fetchValues={fetchValues} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This works great, but only once. What is an idiomatic way to make the component call `fetchValues()` again when something else changes in my application? (It's also acceptable if `fetchValues()` is called on every render, except the ones triggered by the effect itself.)

Comment: Does Dropdown receive a prop that changes? Something other than fetchValues?

Comment: The useEffect function will only trigger when `props.fetchValues` changes. In the code you've posted, it doesn't look like it is changing?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky At the moment there isn't. One possibility is to add a "fake" prop just for this but it feels a bit of a hack.

Comment: @dwjohnston Indeed, which is why that effect runs only once. I could in theory change the identity of `props.fetchValues` to signal that it needs to be called again, but that sounds very brittle.

Comment: Why not instead pass the resolved options to this component instead? Does the parent component of this component know when options change? Disregarding this component, how would you know when to grab new/updated options?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky In the real code the parent doesn't, but some component way up the hierarchy obviously does. If push comes to shove, I can put the logic there but it doesn't quite fit in and I was hoping for a cleaner solution. It feels my use case should be quite a common one. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, so either pass that prop down multiple levels and add it it the array of dependencies of useEffect, use context api to pass down options or that prop, or use something like redux to get options from a store that’s updated at the component that witnesses that change. Just some possible approaches.

Answer (score 2):

useEffect last parameter is the dependency list (when any value changes inside this list it will call useEffect again), you just include [props.fetchValues] so useEffect will be called only when fetchValues changes.

you have 2 options:

- pass the other props throw (state management like redux, context api,
  or props throw parents) and add it to the list, like this

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
   props.fetchValues().then(setOptions);
  }, [props.fetchValues, props.otherProps]);
  ```
- leave the dependency null (do not write empty list), and in this
  state it will be called whenever anything change in your app, like
  this

  ```
   useEffect(() => {
   props.fetchValues().then(setOptions);});
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the solution I went with, the one that appears the cleanest was to abandon the idea altogether and just pass the options themselves as props, leaving fetching (and caching) to a custom hook used by a component much higher up the hierarchy.

As far as I can tell, the reason my original idea didn't work neatly is that I broke the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1):

```js
useEffect(() => {
      props.fetchValues().then(setOptions);
  }, [props.fetchValues, SOMETHING]);
```

where `SOMETHING` is the thing that changes in your application that may trigger the fetch (the best is get this value from props or context)